# Navigation in between pages using ListView in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, navigation, uwp

I am trying to navigate in between pages using listitems but its not working. My home page is MainPage.xaml and I want to navigate to "xyz" when I click on the Aba image in listview

Here is my code:

```
namespace abc
{

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<Class1> list1 = new ObservableCollection<Class1>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Filldata();
    }

    void Filldata()
    {
        list1.Add(new Class1 { name = "Aba", image = "ms-appx:///images/aba.png" });
        list1.Add(new Class1 { name = "Al", image = "ms-appx:///images/al.png" });
    }

    private void itemclicked(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var nme = (Class1)e.ClickedItem;

        switch (nme.name)
        {
            case "Aba":
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(xyz),null);
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="list" ItemClick="itemclicked">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="{Binding image}"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Class1.cs

```
class Class1
{
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String image { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think we need more information to go on. What is the current behavior when clicking on the list item? Does it actually make it to the Navigate method call, but doesn't navigate? Dows class "xyz" inherit from page?

Comment: Not immediately clear, why you aren't calling the overload [Frame.Navigate(TypeName)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702396.aspx). At any rate, there is a return value you are ignoring.

Comment: I just tested it and problem is that are not "enabled" list items to be clicked... you need to add IsItemClickEnabled="True" to your ListView, I wrote answer, you can see it at answer section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an issue with your **ListView** control and the main reason is that you don't have this property in your ListView in XAML:

> **IsItemClickEnabled="True"**

So in order to solve your problem add this property **IsItemClickEnabled="True"** at ListView in XAML page like this:

```
 <ListView x:Name="list"
           ItemClick="itemclicked"
           IsItemClickEnabled="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="100"
                           Width="100"
                           Source="{Binding image}"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```

Your code is fine at navigation methods and other things but you need to "enable" items to be clicked, so add that property in order to can use them with click events.